# Clang skips processing of an initializer list construction

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, language-lawyer

If you look at the following code, I think that both the lines in `main()` should call the `initializer_list` constructor for `InitSomething`. gcc outputs `22` as I expected, but clang just outputs a single `2`. Is clang wrong?

I am compiling with `-std=c++14`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct InitSomething {
    explicit InitSomething(int) { std::cout << '1'; }
    InitSomething(std::initializer_list<int> ) { std::cout << '2'; }
    operator int() { return 1; }
};

int main() {
    InitSomething init_something{1};
    InitSomething init_something_else{init_something};
}
```

---

The output of `clang++ --version` (I am on a mac) is

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

and the output of `g++ --version` on the other platform I mentioned is

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: There has been changes to the language recently, not to favor initializer_list for **every** set of  `{some_value}` if there are other constructors taking `some_value` directly.

Comment: @BoPersson You are referring to C++17 right?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when it appeared. Looking for a reference...

Comment: Ok, I think it has to do with [Core Defect Report #1467 -  List-initialization of aggregate from same-type object](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467). This has the complication that if it was a defect in C++14, the change might be applied retroactively (as a  bug fix to the compiler).

Comment: @BoPersson `InitSomething` isn't an aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

DR1467's title concerns aggregates, but [the wording it added to [dcl.init.list]/3](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) as the first bullet is not limited to aggregates:

> If `T` is a class type and the initializer list has a single element
>   of type `cv U`, where `U` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, the
>   object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>   copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>   direct-list-initialization).

However, [DR2137](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0384r0.html#2137) walked back from this wording (replacing "a class type" with "an aggregate class"), and so [this bullet](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3) no longer applies to non-aggregates like `InitSomething`.

Instead, [dcl.init.list]/3.6 applies, like it did pre-DR1467:

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered.
>   The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one
>   is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match],
>   [over.match.list]).

And [[over.match.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list) makes clear that initializer-list constructors are preferred if at all viable:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized such
>   that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed
>   according to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects
>   the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class `T` and the argument list
>     consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution  is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the elements of the initializer list.

All this talk about ranking implicit conversion sequences is irrelevant because the non-initializer-list constructors *are not even candidates*.

Clang is implementing the wording after DR1467 and before DR2137.

Comment: This sort of thing makes me seriously question `initializer_list` as a concept.